# How do I display buttons with a cube (made in openGL es on android)?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to android and openGL ES. I have created a cube using opengl and now i want to add sum functionalities through buttons. But the problem is if i add buttons to my main.xml file, they are not visible once cube appears.
I need to know how can i see buttons with the cube being displayed in window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your glsurfaceview to a container then add a container with buttons on top of the container holding the glsurfaceview. I've done that before.

So that's two container.

The first one holds the glsurfaceview and the second container.

The second container will hold the buttons.

I don't specify a container's name because maybe by the time you read this, every current container will be obsolete.